# User-defined Suffixes

Tags: c#

Just as the declaraion `float x = 1.0f` is valid and the suffix `f` tells the compiler that it should treat the characters between it and the equal sign as a float, is there any way we can define our own suffixes for classes we implement? Say, for example, you have the class

```
class CustomString
{
    string part1;
    string part2;
}
```

and you want to use the code

`CustomString Test = abc.defX`

where `X` is the suffix to tell the compiler to initialize `part1` with `"abc"` and `part2` with `"def"`? Of course something like this must be built over a constructor, but I am really interested only in the suffix-definition part.

Comment: `1.0f` is a floating-point constant. There's nothing magic about the equals sign - `(1f/10)` is a valid expression, for example.

Comment: So the question should be: is it possible to define new types of constant? (and perhaps to have code that runs at compile time, instead that at run-time). I always thought that compile time code would be very useful for some things (for example for default values of optional parameters). Yeah... Linq is more usefull, and so are generics... As usefull as interfaces for standard math operations I would say.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, there isn't any way to do that.

Comment: Technically you could write a C# rewriter, like they did with the Async CTP. Your code is parsed and modified before giving it to the compiler. The Visual Studio would scream a little....